# rails update method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I ma trying to update the b object. Whenever I run the update method it updates the b object but does not effects the database. I have tried to find the solution but I was not unable to find it's solution. Please tell me what am I doing wrong and if any of you guys who views this question was able to find it's solution please refer that solution to me.

```
    data = params[:d]
    #data1 = params[:d1]
    data2 = data1
    request_bookmarked = Request.getRequest(data)
    bookmarked_against_Request = Request.first
    request_bookmarked_2 = request_bookmarked
    bookmarked_against_Request_2 = bookmarked_against_Request
    b = Bookmark.where(request_id: bookmarked_against_Request[:_id]).first()

    if b !=  nil
      flag = false
      ind = 0;
      b[:corsponding_requests].each.with_index do |t , index|
        if t == request_bookmarked[:id]
          flag = true
          ind = index
        end
      end
      if flag ==  true 
    b1 = b
    #b1.delete_at(ind)#request_bookmarked[:_id])
    b1[:corsponding_requests].delete(request_bookmarked[:id])
    bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites].delete(request_bookmarked[:_d])
    request_bookmarked[:favourites_of].delete(bookmarked_against_Request[:_id])

    b2 = Hash.new
    b2['corsponding_requests'] = Array.new
    b2['corsponding_requests'].push(*b1[:corsponding_requests])
    #b.update(Hash['corsponding_requests' , b1[:corsponding_requests]])
    if b.update_attributes(b2)
      flash[:notice] = "Request has been un bookmarked ."
    end
```

Bookmark.rb(Bookmark Model Class)

```
class Bookmark
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :owner_req, type: String
  field :request_id, type: String
  field :corsponding_requests, type: Array

class << self
    def createBookmark ( title)
          bookmark = self.new(title);
          if bookmark.save
            bookmark
          end
    end


  end

end
```

Comment: Is your b valid? You should check for that first.

Comment: What do you mean by valid ?

Comment: Assuming you are loading your `b`from database, have you performed this check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html . If you can tell how you are creating the b object, its more easy to understand whats causing the trouble.

Comment: What happens if you try to do the update_attributes with those objects in the Rails console?

Comment: it updates the b object but does not effects the database @Bob.

Answer (score 0):

The Update method will fail if the object is invalid in any way. See: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update

Have you tried checking to see if there are any errors preventing the save from happening? Try checking b.errors by puts'ing it or by sticking a binding.pry in right before your update happens.

Comment: can you please tell me how puts'ing or the binding.pry method works because I've never tried it. Thanks

Comment: Hi James, if you have a Gemfile, add a line for `gem 'pry'`. Other wise you can just `gem install pry` from the command line. Then you can add `binding.pry` inside any method code that you want to investigate. It's similar to adding `debugger` in Javascript code. Check out http://pryrepl.org/ for more details on how to use Pry. It's super handy!

Comment: Yeah it helped but the object is in the correct state. The object does not have any garbage or anything like this